# How to start the current time when the installation is done

Tags: android

How to start the time when the installation is done, I also want to calculate and display the number of remaining days for the expiry date by day.

How to use this code at the time of the installation, if any body very familour with this please help me out.

I simply want to implement a trial period for my app, and also for each twenty four hours, I want to show to the user the remaining days for the expire of the app. I dont want to worry about the Uninstallation and again installing the app.

Comment: What's wrong with storing the time the app was first started? The rest is then simple arithmetic.

Comment: sounds like you want to implement a trial period for your app. This doesn't work very well on Android unless you can use an external server to determine whether the trial has already been taken for the current user as otherwise simply uninstalling the app and reinstalling would allow a new trial period.

Comment: @ Henry as @kuffs told i simply want to implement a trial period for my app. and also for the each twenty four hours i want to show to the user the remaining days for the expire of the app. I dont want to worry about the Uninstallation and again installing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store date value in shared preference when your app opens for the first time
then follow the below code

```
Date StoredDate = new Date(prefs.getLong("time", CurrentDate.getTime())); // store this on first installation 

Date CurrentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());// check every time when app opens

    if(daysBetween(StoredDate,CurrentDate)>=10) //** check  the condition for number of days *//*
        {
            condition_Install_valid(MainActivity.this);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Version Expired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.commit();
        }
```

/** Code to check the date object and give days */

```
public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
    return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

//check first run

```
 boolean firstrun = getSharedPreference("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
    if (firstrun){
   [[ ...Display the dialog ]]
    // Save the state
    getSharedPreference("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
editor.putLong("time", CurrentDate.getTime());
        .putBoolean("firstrun", false)
        .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok fine !! now i have a hope that i can finish the task !! but how to store the time at the time of the installation in shared preference???

Comment: you will have to chck the first run of application and store date over there

Comment: ok fine !!! @ Auto-Droid

Comment: If its working upVote my answer and close the question

Comment: sorry @Auto-Droid i cant get the code when am  doing this i cant even get the syntax formation of the code !! please can brief me little bit more about the first run code  ???and also am using the joda time library is it worthable to use ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48254/discussion-between-madhan-devan-and-auto-droid-)